# primefaces p:inputSwitch not work in dialog while use update the dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am doing a on-off with p:inputSwitch, it's in a dialog. When an ajax call inside a form happens in combination with an update on the inputSwitch, the inputSwitch behaves strange and always resets its state. Here is a simple reproducible example (without the need of a backing bean):

```
<h:form id="buttonForm">
    <p:commandButton value="button" update="switch" oncomplete="PF('switchDialog').show();" />
    <p:dialog widgetVar="switchDialog">
        <p:inputSwitch id="switch" />
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

Interesting observations:

- When you remove the `h:form` the problem is gone
- When you remove the `update` parameter it works
- When the `p:inputSwitch` is outside of the `p:dialog` it also works

Comment: Please post the code of `myView` what is `b1` or `b2` doing?

Comment: I reproduced your example, but I don't know what you mean with "then the p:inputSwitch component not work". What do you mean? In your example b1 works for me because of the `update`, b2 doesn't work because of the missing `update` parameter. Please be more concise what does not work, and what should be expected.

Comment: the func in myView did nothing. And there are code:                            
 public void b1(){} 
 public void b2(){}

Comment: It's my fault.I did not clearly explain my problem.In this example,if i click the button named "b1",the dialog show,and while i click on  the inputSwitch component,it changed and changed back(eg:befor i click it ,it's on state "on",i click the component,it chang to state "off" and rechange to state "on"),but in the b2 button,it is not happend.I test this in firefox many times and not tested on chrome yet.

Comment: I now reproduced your issue. I edited your post with an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - when peer reviewing is done maybe someone else can help you.

Comment: someone solved it? it's happens the same for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for this zombie post but i've found a solution that can help.

Add in your

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="switchDialog" dynamic="true">
```

Regards